# working with openGL

Tags: opengl, lighting

im trying to do a little 3d scene with openGL and include a bit of lighting, im fine with my scene (although it isnt anything special) and im trying to add some lighting to give it some effect. however I can add material to my podium (which isnt textured) and that gives me light and anything that IS textured does not apply any material to it so it defies the point of having lights. Heres some of the code.

```
// Setup GL_LIGHT0
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient);     // Setup ambient light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuse);     // Setup diffuse light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightSpecular);   // Setup specular light

glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, ca);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, la);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, qa);

glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 180.0f);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 0.0);

// Setup GL_LIGHT1
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient);     // Setup ambient light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuse);     // Setup diffuse light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, lightSpecular);   // Setup specular light

glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, ca);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, la);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, qa);

glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 180.0f);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 0.0);
// Setup GL_LIGHT2
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient);     // Setup ambient light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuse);     // Setup diffuse light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_SPECULAR, lightSpecular);   // Setup specular light

glLightf(GL_LIGHT2, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, ca);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT2, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, la);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT2, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, qa);

glLightf(GL_LIGHT2, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 180.0f);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT2, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 0.0);
// Setup GL_LIGHT3
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT3, GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient);     // Setup ambient light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT3, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuse);     // Setup diffuse light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT3, GL_SPECULAR, lightSpecular);   // Setup specular light

glLightf(GL_LIGHT3, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, ca);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT3, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, la);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT3, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, qa);

glLightf(GL_LIGHT3, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 180.0f);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT3, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 0.0);

// OpenGL provides a global ambient light component - we don't want this so set to zero
GLfloat global_ambient[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, global_ambient);
```

And to render my room + 3d object.

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT2);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT3);

    // Define position and direction
    // NOTE: Placing these commands AFTER the above viewing (camera) transformations means the light position and direction appear to have a set point / direction in the 3D environment.  If these commands are placed BEFORE the above viewing transformations, then the light appears to move with the camera (as if it is attached to the camera!)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, lightDirection);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, lightDirection1);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, lightPosition1);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, lightDirection2);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_POSITION, lightPosition2);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT3, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, lightDirection3);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT3, GL_POSITION, lightPosition3);


    // setup materials for objects to draw
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, ambientMaterial);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseMaterial);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, specularMaterial);


    // 2. Draw scene
    glPushMatrix();
        drawRoom();
        glTranslatef(0.0,-0.75,0.0);
        glRotatef(90.0, 1.0,0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(-spin, 0.0,0.0, 1.0);
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        drawPodium();
    glPopMatrix();

    // Save transformations prior to rendering scene
    glPushMatrix();

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);   

        // Setup texture state
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

        glRotatef(spin, 0.0,1.0, 0.0);
        // Render model

        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseMaterial2);

        glTranslatef(0.0,0.8,0.0);
        glRotatef(1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);
        myModel->renderTexturedModel();

        // Reset texture state
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // restore transformations after rendering scene
    glPopMatrix();
```

And the current outcome with my 4 lights, in a square shape above the helicopter all looking down towards 0.0 is:

[image: My scene]

If you can make out the white dotted lines they are the direction the lights are looking. the surface of the podium is lit and the sides of the podium are lit as it spins. However the rest of the room and helicopter does not respond to light and act like lighting isnt even enabled hence why i think its because everything except the podium is textured.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to setup glTexEnv to specify how lighting should work for the textured objects

See:

21.030 Why doesn't lighting work when I turn on texture mapping?
http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/texture.htm

Or to address your problem more directly, the line

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
```

is what causes the behaviour. As the faq explains, when you specify GL_REPLACE, you replace the primitive lighting colour with the texture colour, which overwrites any lighting calculations. You can remove this line completely as GL_MODULATE is the default behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i see what your saying, got rid of the line though and it's still the same :(

Comment: What happens in myModel->renderTexturedModel(); ?

Comment: This is the function with the comment. I can't actually see the hard code.
    // Render textured model if texture attached.  This assumes texture state has been setup
 // This includes glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) and glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, <mode>);
 void renderTexturedModel() const;

Comment: it basically deals with in my case a .3ds model, i use an attach texture function so it knows the location of the texture file, and that function will then render, from the comments there shouldnt be any "glTexEnv" decleration in that function. i have noticed though that somehow the rotor blades on top of the helicopter seem to be black (as if its now accepting light) yet the walls and floor of the room and main body of the helicopter still doesnt :/

Comment: Hmm code you can't see isn't always that helpful. Have you tried actually using GL_MODULATE? It might just be that your light setup isn't doing what you think it should be doing but it does work. Lighting relies on normals being specified for one. Try a very basic lighting setup and see if you can get that to work first.

Comment: yeh i tried that, tried declaring it at the top, and after each thing i render too. its being really mean :(

Comment: well the lighting i have in works on the podium (which is non textured) now, for some reason my rotor blades are accepting the light as well. and i can light them if i put a light above the helicopter. doesnt quite make sense that it wouldnt apply to the entire model :/

Comment: It's likely that what you are seeing is the specular component. You have to be looking down so see that effect based on your lighting setup. Try rotating your model so that it's sideways and look at one of its sides. Does it give you the same effect?

Comment: SOLVED! the fact i have four lights (even though directional) seem to just totally light the room, if i switch them all off its completely dark and switching 1 on lights the scene a little bit :D thank you muchly!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the above method works for you. I had the same problem. My problem was that I had not specified the normals of the object.

//specify normals 
glNormal3f();

hopefully this will solve the problem for anyone (i tried every other method over the internet but nothing worked; only this method worked).